# SPOTFIRE, calculate value based on a condition

Tags: bigdata, spotfire

i would like to show the name of the process that has the most amount of delayed status

| Process | status |
| --- | --- |
| A | FINISHED |
| B | DELAYED |
| B | DELAYED |
| B | DELAYED |

how would i show the name of the process B, which has the most amount of delayed statuses, in a text field?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to first create a calculated column, say called [N_Delayed], defined as:

```
case  when [status]='DELAYED' then Count([STATUS]) over ([Process]) end
```

Then open and edit a new Text area, select to add a Dynamic Item > Calculated Value, then define the Values as this Custom Expression (right click on drop down under 'Calculate Values using:' to edit the Custom Expression):

```
ValueForMax([N_Delayed],[Process])
```